# Styling problems with Chart.Js

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

**How can I add these styles to my graph?** I'm having trouble finding it in the documentation for it, and the other forums aren't very helpful.  I am using Flask for the backend, so that's why the data values look like that.

- Labels on top of bars
- Change font size on both axis
- Set y scale as a fixed value (0,8)

```
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var options = {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                fontSize: 40
                    }
                }]
            }
    }
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['Lithium Battery', 'Other Mfg', 'Delivery', 'Tailpipe', 'Fuel Cycle', 'Disposal', 'Total'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'ICEV CAR (MTCO2e/Year)',
            labels: [
                "{{data['battery_icev_car']}}",
                "{{data['other_mfg_icev_car']}}", 
                "{{data['delivery_icev_car']}}", 
                "{{data['tailpipe_icev_car']}}",
                "{{data['fuel_cycle_icev_car']}}", 
                "{{data['disposal_icev_car']}}", 
                "{{data['total_icev_car']}}"
            ],
            data: [  /* errors are normal, fixes when server ru
                [0, {{data['y1_icev']}}],
                [{{data['y1_icev']}}, {{data['y2_icev']}}],
                [{{data['y2_icev']}}, {{data['y3_icev']}}],
                [{{data['y3_icev']}}, {{data['y4_icev']}}],
                [{{data['y4_icev']}}, {{data['y5_icev']}}],
                [{{data['y5_icev']}}, {{data['y6_icev']}}],
                [0, {{data['y6_icev']}}]
            ],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(0,0,0,0.9)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(0,0,0,1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderSkipped: false
        }]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                labels: {
                    // This doesn't work on axis
                    font: {
                        size: 20
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        y: {
            beginAtZero: true
        }
    }
});
</script>         </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your config is not working I assume you are using V3, in which case the solution is as followed:

For point one you need to use an external plugin, you can write your own or use the [datalabels plugin](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/)

For your second problem you need to style it as a font object as told in the [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/axes/cartesian/linear.html#common-tick-options-to-all-axes) like so:

```js
options: {
  scales: {
    y:{
      ticks:{
        font:{
           size: 50
         }
       }
    }
  }
}
```

For your last part you can set the [`stepSize`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/axes/cartesian/linear.html#linear-axis-specific-tick-options) to 0.8